# Smooth transform SVG vertically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, svg

In my index.html I have:

`<ellipse id="ellipseRed" cx="500" cy="1300" rx="40" ry="150" />`

In my javascript file I have:

```
$('ellipse').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('transform', 'translate(0 -350) rotate(0)');
});
```

The transform works, but it is not smooth. That is it seems to "jump" to its new location rather than transition into it.

I want to click the SVG ellipse and have it slowly move vertically up. Then If I click it again, have it slowly move down.

I'm new html, SVG, and jQuery/Javascript

Am I even going about this the right way? Should I be using jQuery to animate this SVG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to animate SVG with jQuery it is awkward and not very efficient. I'd suggest using a library with good SVG support such as [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com) or [D3](http://d3js.org).

This is how you would do it in jQuery:

```
//jQuery way, not recommended
$('#ellipseRed').click(function() {
    //min-height is just a placeholder value
    //so jquery knows what values to put into
    //the transformation
    $(this)
    .css({"min-height": 0})
    .animate(
      {"min-height": -350},
      {duration: 1000,
       step: function( top ){
           this.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0,"+top+")");
         }
       });
});
```

Compare how clear this is in D3:

```
d3.select("#ellipseBlue").on("click", function(){
  d3.select(this)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .ease("in-out")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,-350)")
});
```

You can find a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LupTw/

​

Answer (score 0):

For animation you must use translate.
Example you can see here http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/#4

Comment: Animating SVG Elements with CSS transitions is only supported on Webkit.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It's very relevant to what I am learning now.